# Front Page 2003 replacement

Tags: microsoft-office-2003, frontpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any free open source HTML editors?](https://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors)

Hello. I have Microsoft Office 2003 installed, but no frontpage is installed. I don't know why not. It was an OEM installation.

Can anyone recommend an open source replacement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrontPage is now discontinued.

It was replaced by [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/fx100487631033.aspx)

SharePoint Designer is now [free](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=baa3ad86-bfc1-4bd4-9812-d9e710d44f42)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint_Designer):

> Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer
>   is a free WYSIWYG HTML editor and web
>   design program from Microsoft  for
>   SharePoint and other websites and is
>   part of the SharePoint family of
>   products. It is part of the Microsoft
>   Office 2007 family, but not included
>   in any of the Office 2007 suites. The
>   name change, from FrontPage, reflects
>   the emphasis on designing and
>   customizing SharePoint websites, while
>   Microsoft Expression Web is the
>   full-featured successor to FrontPage.
>   SharePoint Designer shares its
>   codebase, UI and HTML rendering engine
>   with Microsoft Expression Web, and
>   does not rely on Internet Explorer's
>   Trident engine, which is less
>   standards compliant.[1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/fx100487631033.aspx)  One of its
>   differences from the general web
>   design application, Expression Web, is
>   that it does include only
>   SharePoint-specific site templates. It
>   retains more FrontPage features than
>   Expression Web such as web components,
>   database, marquee, hit counter,
>   navigation bars, insert maps etc.

Comment: It looks like there is a free Expression Web trial at http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/default.aspx?filter=web3, though the software costs money after the trial

Comment: SharePoint Designer is free forever!

Comment: Sharepoint designer was not the replacement.  Expression web products replaced FrontPage. You can alos do simple HTML editing in Word

Comment: @DaveM - Yes and no. Whilst Expression replaced FrontPage as Microsoft's commercial web design app, SharePoint Designer is also a replacement as it is the same code base, just renamed for the new version and with specific SharePoint Server functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

FrontPage has never been part of any Office 2003 install I have seen.  Sorry I can't suggest an alternate.

Comment: FP2003 was indeed a standalone only product. More info on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage

Answer (score 0):

[KomPozer](http://www.kompozer.net/) is a decent open source WYSIWIG html editor, though it doesn't replicate the full functionality of FrontPage.

I personally use Emacs for most of my HTML editing needs, but I doubt that is what you're looking for coming from FrontPage.

Comment: All I want to be able to do is format short email PR announcements regarding musical shows I am producing.

Comment: I think you should be fine with this then - it behaves similarly to a word processor.