# What WYSIWYG software can I use to create a web page?

Tags: website, html, webpage, wysiwyg

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are there any free open source HTML editors?](https://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors)
>   [Please recommand a tool for Html Editing](https://superuser.com/questions/107893/please-recommand-a-tool-for-html-editing)

I always made web pages by writing HTML code but now I would like to try to use some WYSIWYG approach. Can anybody recommend me a program which I can use for that? I mean a program in which you can move buttons, tables, pictures by mouse. You can change size and shape by mouse. You can use nice templates for "block of text", buttons, background and so on.

I am using Windows 7. May be I already have something pre-installed?

**ADDED:**

1. Should be free.
2. It should be easy to install.

**ADDED2:**

My main goal is to have a nice design for my web page. I just installed the SealMonkey and it seems to me that it has only basic stuff. I can create some web pages there but they will contain just basic stuff. And I would like to have things like that:

1. Gradient color background.
2. Transparency.
3. Round buttons and tables.

I also installed Amaya and it seems to be more in the direction I like.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors http://superuser.com/questions/121109/front-page-2003-replacement http://superuser.com/questions/110072/what-wysiwyg-html-editor-should-i-give-a-novice http://superuser.com/questions/107893/please-recommand-a-tool-for-html-editing

Comment: Gradient colour backgrounds and round buttons and tables? Yes, they can be achieved, but you will need to use images (8 for rounded corners; top-left, top-middle, top-right, etc) if you do not wish to use CSS3, which is not implemented in the current stable version of Internet Explorer, and which is not implemented in any well-known WYSIWYG editors, as far as I know

Comment: You say you want a WYSIWYG editor for nice designs for your web pages in Nick G's answer. WYSIWYG editors are not particularly geared towards design.

Comment: As you already have knowledge in HTML, CSS, PHP and MySQL, then I think you are best served with designing in Photoshop/Illustrator or other design software and then coding your HTML and CSS manually. No WYSIWYG-HTML-Editor will allow you to actually design, but to try and rebuild a design and then save as HTML/CSS

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing like that preinstalled with Windows 7, AFAIK.

There are many available however, big and small, proprietary or free software.

I have used [KompoZer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KompoZer) (free software) and can recommend it. It is easy enough to use even for relative novices (my mother uses it to update her pages), yet has a lot of power (CSS, source code view). It is not as comprehensive as some other packages though (e.g. little support for automatic navigation).

There is a nice [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors) on wikipedia of editors that might interest you.

Comment: I cannot install it. When I press download I just get a folder with sub-folders and many files and I have no ideas what to do with this files and folders.

Comment: @Roman: You don't need to do anything with it. Just unzip the folder where you like, then run the kompozer.exe inside.

Answer (score 2):

One of Microsoft's replacements for the discontinued FrontPage is [SharePoint Designer 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/default.aspx) and it is [free](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=baa3ad86-bfc1-4bd4-9812-d9e710d44f42).

It is geared towards SharePoint Server but still retains all the functionality of it's predecessor, FrontPage 2003 so it is still a full WYSIWYG HTML editor

FYI: The other replacement is a commercial product call [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/Expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In case you're actually daring enough, Word can do as a very, very basic website creator, but it does create quite a lot of excessive code (since you have experience in HTML I doubt you would go along with this). I would *very, very strongly* recommend against this for that reason, along with a multitude of others. I'll just leave you to read Nick G's comment below.

The next step up would be basic editors like [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/). It's a fork of another editor Nvu. I haven't used KompoZer at all, and have used Nvu a long time ago, and remember it as quite buggy, so KompoZer, being aimed at having things like bugfixes should be quite good.

<s>You can also go further with editors like Dreamweaver, Microsoft Expression Web or SharePoint Designer or Visual Web Developer, but they're more complicated and are paid-for apps (VWD is available in an express version, though, which *is* free.</s>

If you're thinking about more complicated editors, there's applications such as Microsoft's Visual Web Developer Express. It is however more orientated towards advanced users and also has some focus on Microsoft's ASP server side language.

Microsoft also has SharePoint Designer ([2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BAA3AD86-BFC1-4BD4-9812-D9E710D44F42&displaylang=en) and [2010 beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eeda9ab1-ac53-4870-9e1c-38940343d677&displaylang=en)), which is also free, and instead of a focus on ASP it's on SharePoint. But it can still do basic web pages as well as it is essentially the successor to FrontPage, which was part of Office 1997, XP, and 2003.

sleske's answer already has this, but I'll just quickly reiterate, [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors#WYSIWYG_editors) of WYSIWYG editors that you may wish to look into to have a look at the full range of at least somewhat known editors.

Most WYSIWYG editors also have code editing modes, so you could possibly mix in HTML to your workflow.

Comment: No no no! I'm a professional web developer (and the technical director a web development firm) and I would strongly urge you NOT to EVER use Word for anything HTML related! It has extremely poor support for HTML and anything created in Word will become ineditable by any other apps. The HTML it produces is extremely verbose, malformatted and non standards compliant. The HTML is so awful it would also provide little scope for the poster to alter the HTML or even learn HTML if they were to look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a website, but have no interest in learning HTML or getting involved with the technicalites, I would suggest that rather than using software, you actually use an online solution. There are dozens, but as a starting point, I would recommend you have a look at http://www.weebly.com

Comment: @Nick G, as I wrote in my questions I already know HTML quite well. I know PHP and MySQL and CSS. I just decided to use some WYSIWYG software to make a nice design for my web pages.

Comment: Sorry - you did not state your skill level so I assumed you were a novice. A good web developer knows that you don't get good results (good HTML) by using WYSIWYG editors - which is why professional developers rarely use them (nobody in my company does but I have seen non-technical people in the graphic design industry use things like Dreamweaver). I'd stick to editing by hand if possible but perhaps explore template libraries to easily get a good looking site but maintain the quality of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best WYWIWYG HTML editor is still the last version of Mozilla. I run an old PowerPC version on my Mac. I assume the Windows version is just as usable.

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/

They recommend not to use it as your normal browser (and you shouldn't, it's out of date) but the HTML editor is still the best I could find.

Comment: The OP mentions that he has tried SeaMonkey, and you should be aware that it is a continuation of the Mozilla suite. KompoZer has been mentioned, and being a continuation of Nvu, it is essentially a stand-alone version of the Mozilla suite's HTML editor.